# List shared between tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm using one thread to parse the packets and add to the list, then I'm using other thread to itinerate that list and parse the packet.

I can receive the packets and add them to the list, somehow the other thread is still using the outdated version of the list. I tried to use lock to read/write to it but is still happening.

```
private class SocketInformation
{
    public bool open { get; set; }
    private ConcurrentQueue<byte[]> packetReceiveQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<byte[]>();

    public ConcurrentQueue<byte[]> GetPacketReceiveQueue()
    {
        return packetReceiveQueue;
    }
}

private void NewConnection(StreamSocket socket)
{
    SocketInformation socketInformation = new SocketInformation();
    socketInformation.open = true;
    Task.Run(() => ReadPackets(socket, socketInformation));
    Task.Run(() => OnlineLoop(socket, socketInformation));
}

private async void ReadPackets(StreamSocket socket, SocketInformation socketInformation)
{
    // ...
    Debug.WriteLine("Packet received.");

    ConcurrentQueue<byte[]> packetReceiveQueue = socketInformation.GetPacketReceiveQueue();
    packetReceiveQueue.Enqueue(packet);
}

private async void OnlineLoop(StreamSocket socket, SocketInformation socketInformation)
{
    while (socketInformation.open)
    {
        ConcurrentQueue<byte[]> packetReceiveQueue = socketInformation.GetPacketReceiveQueue();

        for (int i = 0; i < packetReceiveQueue.Count; i++)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Parsing packet.");
            byte[] packet = packetReceiveQueue.ElementAt(i);
            ParsePacketSequence(socket, socketInformation, packet);
        }
    }
}
```

Console:

1. Packet received.
2. Packed added to the queue.
3. Parsing packet.
4. Packet received.
5. Packed added to the queue.
6. (Second packet not parsed, list outdated)

Comment: Sorry I had to drop my answer. I believe that I wasn't understanding the question at all based on your source code.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer each connection has a list with all the packets received, using other thread they are read. I'm looking documentation about ConcurrentQueue that may help. Thanks.

Comment: I've edited your question. It was hard for me to see that some methods were from an outer class... Change `WhoKnows` with whatever if you want...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Ohh, sorry. I see what are talking about. thanks again.

Comment: @BrokenGlass I consider myself stupid too, sorry! :/

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but 99% that using the concurrent queue should solve the issue, but since I can't prove now (I need to go away from the computer), I just give you this hint ;p

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Yeah, it will kinda difficult to group everything within the class tho. I'm using it with global variables and less-related functions that will make the code more confusing.

Comment: Why are the methods async? It makes zero sense to have an async method that doesn't await.

Comment: @EricLippert I deleted non-relevant code.

Comment: You have a threading problem involving running asynchronous code on multiple threads and sharing a non-threadsafe collection between them using locks. **There is no non-relevant code.** That's why getting it right is so hard. Make a **complete** runnable example that **clearly** demonstrates the problem; until you do that there is no telling what the mistake is. If the code you posted demonstrates the bug then get rid of the asyncs; those are just red herrings.

Comment: @EricLippert ReadPackets use await for ReadAsync and OnlineLoop uses await Task.Delay(33) to run at 30 ticks per second. Looks good, right?

Answer (score 1):

There are [Thread-Safe Collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) built-in to .net. Find the one that best suits your need. (Looks like [ConcurrentQueue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would be best - it's FIFO.)

Comment: I've updated my code, same issue happens. It's being added to the local variable, or is the class another instance?

Comment: @MiguelRipoll I haven't analyzed your code (I'm not even the right person to do that) but the correct way to get the object you need from a ConcurrentQueue is (AFAIK) to use [TryDequeue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287208%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) .

Comment: I just now read some of the comments above and saw that you were aware of ConcurrentQueue  to begin with. I'm ready to delete my answer. I'm leaving it just in case the links in it are what you were looking for. Please let me know if you don't need the answer and I should delete it.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Then I can't use ConcurrentQueue as packets are removed when itinerated. I need to store packets that may need to be ordered so deleting it doesn't help :/ Thanks anyways. Edit: I can use TryPeek.